# How to call another method from a self method with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def self.method1(param1)
    # Here I want to call method2 with a parameter
    method2(param2)
  end

  def method2(param2)
    # Do something
  end
end
```

I call method1 from controller. When I run the program. I got an error:

```
method_missing(at line method2(param2))
.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in find_each
...
```

Comment: This would work for the class Class:)

Comment: What is a "self method"?

Comment: This took me too much time to find, so for future googlers: this is the answer to "Ruby/Rails how to call a static method from a static method."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def self.method1(param1)
    # Here I want to call method2 with a parameter
    method2(param2)
  end

  def self.method2(param2)
    # Do something
  end
end
```

Explanation: first one is a class method, the latter was an instance method. Class methods don't need a receiver (an object who call them), instance methods need it. So, you can't call an instance method from a class method because you don't know if you have a receiver (an instanciated object who call it).

Comment: So class methods are restricted to interacting with other class methods .. what if class methods wants to talk to the private methods? should they also be declared as private def self.bla end ?

Comment: Yes, and a private self.bla is a class method, not an instance method. But a class method might instanciate an object and call an instance method on it, if it makes sense.

Comment: (1) The receiver of a method call (which is actually a message send, hence the name of the `send` method) is the object receiving the message, i.e. the object "owning" the method. (2) "Class methods" (which technically are instance methods of the class's singleton class; Ruby has no actual class methods at all) also have a receiver: the singleton class of the `Product` class object. In fact, you can only ever call methods on a receiver, even if it's just the implicit `self`. This stems from Ruby's "everything is an object" premise.

Comment: You're right. I did not know how to write this shortly. There are books for these concepts.

Comment: "first one is a class method, the latter was an instance method" – That's misleading. Yes, we sometimes use the term "class method" in Ruby, when talking to people who already understand Ruby. But the OP clearly doesn't, so that term should best be avoided. There are no class methods in Ruby. There are only instance methods. `method1` is an instance method of the singleton class of `Product`.

Comment: "Class methods don't need a receiver (an object who call them)" – This is doubly wrong. First, the receiver is not the caller, it's the callee. Second, of course, class methods have a receiver: the class.

Comment: @JörgWMittag would you like to correct my answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because `method2` is not defined for `Product` object.

`method2` is an instance method, and can be called only on the instance of `Product` class.

Answer (score 1):

Of course @Ursus and @Andrey Deineko answers are right solution of this problem. Besides that, if anyone want to know how we can call `instance` method with in `class method(though this is not actually class method in ruby)` for those `self.new.instance_method`.